# jQuery slider doesn't rotate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slider rotator on my site but it doesn't rotate items automatically in the boxes - navigation works and rotate but I want it to rotate automatically, right after I enter the site.
This is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var nbr = 0;
   $('.slider').each(function() {
      var slider = $(this);

   //get width and height of the wrapper and give it to the UL
    var wrapperwidth = $(slider).width() *  $(slider).find('ul > li').size();
    $(slider).find('ul').css('width', wrapperwidth);
    var wrapperheight = $(slider).height();
    $(slider).find('ul').css('height', wrapperheight);


   //set my li width
    var width = $(slider).width();
    $(slider).find('ul li').css('width', width);

   //set my counter vars
    var counter = $(slider).find('ul > li').size();
    var decount = 1;
    var autocount = 1;

      if (counter > 1) {
      //create my number navigation
        var createNum = 1;
         $(slider).after('<ul class="numbers"><li></li></ul>');
        var numbers = $(slider).parent().find('.numbers');
         $(numbers).find('li:first-child').html(createNum+'_'+nbr).addClass('activenum').attr('id', 'id1_'+nbr);
        while ( createNum != counter) {
            createNum++;
           $(numbers).append("<li id='id"+createNum+"_"+nbr+"'>"+createNum+"_"+nbr+"</li>");
        }

      //get my number-width (number navigation should always be centered)
        var numwidth = $(slider).find('.numbers li:first-child').width() * $(slider).find('.numbers li').size();
        $(slider).find('.numbers').css('width', numwidth);
      }

      nbr++;
   });



   //make the number clickable
   $(".numbers li").click(function() {
      var slider = $(this).closest('.sliderWrapper');
      var slider0 = $(slider).find('.slider');
    var clickednum = $(this).html().split('_')[0] * - $(slider0).width() + $(slider0).width();
    $(slider0).find('ul').animate({ left: clickednum }, 400, 'swing', function() { });
    $(slider).find('.activenum').removeClass('activenum');
    $(this).addClass('activenum');
    decount = $(this).html();
   });



   rotateSwitch = function(sliderW, speed) {
      var sliderWrap = sliderW;
      play = setInterval(function() {
         var nextNum = parseInt($($(sliderWrap).find(".numbers li.activenum")).html().split('_')[0])+1;
         if (nextNum > $(sliderWrap).find(".numbers li").length) {
            nextNum = 1;
         }
         //console.log("nextnum: "+nextNum+", numbers length: "+$(sliderWrap).find(".numbers li").length);
         $(sliderWrap).find(".numbers li").each(function() {
            if( parseInt($(this).html().split('_')[0]) == nextNum )
               $(this).click();
         });
      }, speed);
   };

   makeAutoSlide = function(sliderWrap, speed) {
      if ($(sliderWrap).length > 0 && $(sliderWrap).find(".numbers li").length > 1) {
         rotateSwitch(sliderWrap, speed);

         $(sliderWrap).find(".slider li").hover(function() {
            if ($(sliderWrap).find(".numbers li").length > 1) {
               clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
            }
        }, function() {
           if ($(sliderWrap).find(".numbers li").length > 1) {
               rotateSwitch(sliderWrap, speed); //Resume rotation timer
           }
        });
      }
   };


});
```

I'm not really sure if this is a problem with setInterval and clearInterval or I wrote something wrong.

I put code in jsFiddle, so you know how the structure looks like.
http://jsfiddle.net/gecbjerd/1/

I appreciate for help.
Cheers

Comment: The fiddle doesn't reproduce the problem. Please, try to share a valid code that reproduces your issue

Comment: This is why I wrote that fiddle is only for the HTML structure, basically this rotator is used in CMS so there are a lot of lines containes CMS commands, so this won't work. All I want to know If I wrote something wrong in this js or clearinterval and setinterval are used wrong way

Comment: Where do you are calling `makeAutoSlide()` function? If you don't call the auto-rotation functions you can't achieve it.

Comment: Actually nowhere oO. Where should I call it ?

Comment: At the end of document.ready. `$(document).ready(function() { [...... all your code .....] makeAutoSlide(); });`

Comment: Ahh I don't get it... It doesn't work :/

Comment: This code doesn't make by you, true? Where do you copy it? If you don't know how this works or how it was build, this simple task can make you crazy. You need to put the function at the end of the `each()` because it needs two arguments to pass: `makeAutoSlide($(this), 5000)` that means auto slide the instanced slider and rotate each 5 seconds.

Comment: Yeah, this is not my code, I took over this project after someone else - this is why im trying to understand it. Atm it started to work. But there are 2 things which doesn't. I have 4 boxes in which this slider is put, in first 2 I have 3 elements, in 3rd there are 6 and in 4th there are like 10. It slides content in boxes but once it get to 3rd elements in all boxes it stop and don't rotate again

Comment: So you don't have any documentation, I guess.... It's painful I suppose for you. Sorry. I was read all this code and seems to looks all ok. I made some things in different way but the code must work. Maybe you are writting the different structures in the same wrapper. It's possible?

Comment: Yeah exactly I have nothing I can base on :/ the code looks fine and i have no idea why it doesnt want to loop and stop in the middle :/

Comment: Your js console throws any error? Are you debugging step-by-step? If you don't know how, this tutorial can help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger (this is for Firefox but chrome has one similar). Please, debug and see what are the values of the variables, what is the step that breaks the script, what is the errors that throws the console, etc.